# Why is std::bad_alloc thrown by get_driver_instance()?

Tags: c++, mysql, driver

I'm trying to run a C++ MySQL example from the mysql.com website.

```
#define DBHOST "tcp://127.0.0.1:3306/"
#define USER "root"
#define PASSWORD ""

//...

string url(DBHOST);
const string user(USER);
const string password(PASSWORD);
const string database(DATABASE);

try {
    driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();

    /* create a database connection using the Driver */

    con = driver->connect(url, user, password);
```

I get:

```
First-chance exception at 0x75c99673 in DBTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception:      std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0027f1ec..
First-chance exception at 0x75c99673 in DBTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0027eb78..
First-chance exception at 0x75c99673 in DBTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
Unhandled exception at 0x75c99673 in DBTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0027eb78..
The program '[1236] DBTest.exe: Native' has exited with code -529697949 (0xe06d7363).
```

…at `driver->connect(...)`. I've tried without assigning it to `con`, same thing (meaning problem is in `get_driver_instance()`)?

Comment: Did you call `mysql_init()`? (Or the equivalent in the C++ API, I only know the C one)

Comment: Post an actual testcase that can reproduce the issue, please. Your snippet is not a valid C++ program. Also the question title doesn't describe the question.

Comment: If you haven't written much code, I suggest to change your library to [Poco::Data::MySql](http://pocoproject.org/docs/)

Answer (score -1):

It's a little late but for solve this problem, I tried this and it worked for me

```
sql::mysql::Driver *driver = get_driver_instance();

const sql::SQLString host = "tcp://127.0.0.1:3306";
const sql::SQLString user = "root";
const sql::SQLString pass = "*****";

sql::mysql::Connection *con = driver->connect(host, user, pass);
```